# Unable to copy files to USB drive

Tags: usb

It says "Error creating directory: No space left on device" when the truth is my usb has nothing inside it and I tried it with others... same result. I have a 12.04 version of ubuntu.

Comment: What is the size of the file you're trying to copy and what file system that you're using with your usb

Answer (score 2):

Open the "Disks" application

1. Unmount the USB drive (Click on the stop icon)
2. Click on the "gear" icon for menu and select "format.."
3. Format the USB drive as "FAT"

[image]

Comment: @'Danial Jose', What is the software that you have used to edit above screenshot?

Comment: @deroot *Shutter* It is available in Ubuntu software center. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the USB using FAT32 (compatible with all systems).